# Resources about movement and simulation in multiplayer games

Tags: networking, multiplayer, simulations, synchronization

I am developing a multiplayer game, similar to Castle Crashers. This is the first multiplayer game I do so, before starting to code, I am trying to learn what's the best way to do it. I found some documents explaining how some old FPS (Half Life, Quake) work but I can't found anything newer or more similar to the game I am creating.

Do you know any resources to articles about this topic?

Comment: This would be a much better question if you were asking about a specific problem; as it is, it's not really an on-topic question for this site. See [this](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/639/is-asking-for-learning-resources-on-topic) meta topic as well as the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 2):

I start posting the links I found:

- http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Latency_Compensating_Methods_in_Client/Server_In-game_Protocol_Design_and_Optimization
- http://fabiensanglard.net/quakeSource/quakeSourcePrediction.php
- http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/networked-physics/
- http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/NetworkingOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

I watched this a couple of months ago.

http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1014345/I-Shot-You-First-Networking

It's a pretty interesting talk about syncing states in a networked environment.